# Calculator is not working, can't find the problem (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, calculator

I have to program a calculator for my class. I am not very good at this, so I did it exactly like we did it in class but it is not working and I can't find the problem.
I am not looking for the whole solution, just for a tip where the problem is.

The calculator consists of 2 input fields for the numbers and 1 button to add the numbers

```
HTML


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="node_modules"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
   

</head>
<body>
<label for="zahl1"></label>
<input id="zahl1" type="text" placeholder="Zahl eingeben">
<label for="zahl2" type="text"></label>
<input id="zahl2" type="text" placeholder="Zahl eingeben">
<button id="plusBtn" class="btn btn-info">+</button>


<p id="ergebnis"></p>
</body>
</html>


Typescript


document.addEventListener("DomContentLoaded", () => {
    document.getElementById("plusBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
        const zahl1Input = document.getElementById("zahl1") as HTMLInputElement;
        const zahl2Input = document.getElementById("zahl2") as HTMLInputElement;
        const zahl1: number = Number(zahl1Input.value);
        const zahl2: number = Number(zahl2Input.value);
        const sum = zahl1 + zahl2
        let ergebnis: number;
        ergebnis = sum(zahl1, zahl2)

        const ergebnisInput = document.getElementById("ergebnis") as HTMLInputElement;
        ergebnisInput.value = ergebnis.toString();
    })
})
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is not working?

Comment: `sum` is going to be `NaN` or `Number`, not a function.

Comment: "DomContentLoaded" should be DOMContentLoaded, note the capitalization of the first three letters

Comment: @gacci: when I put 2 numbers in the input fields and click the + button it should show the sum of those 2 numbers, but it doesn't show anything

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the code. Compare the differences...

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

  document.getElementById("plusBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const zahl1Input = document.getElementById("zahl1");
    const zahl2Input = document.getElementById("zahl2");
    const zahl1 = Number(zahl1Input.value);
    const zahl2 = Number(zahl2Input.value);
    const sum = zahl1 + zahl2

    let ergebnis;
    ergebnis = sum

    const ergebnisInput = document.getElementById("ergebnis");

    ergebnisInput.innerText = ergebnis.toString();
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="node_modules"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <label for="zahl1"></label>
  <input id="zahl1" type="text" placeholder="Zahl eingeben">
  <label for="zahl2" type="text"></label>
  <input id="zahl2" type="text" placeholder="Zahl eingeben">
  <button id="plusBtn" class="btn btn-info">+</button>


  <p id="ergebnis"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ergebnis = sum(zahl1, zahl2)
```

The problem is here. Using sum(arguments) means you're calling a function called 'sum', but you have not made 'sum' a function but rather a variable containing the sum.

Correct way would be:

```
ergebnis = sum
```

This would work, but you can optimize the code further omitting unnecessary variables.